# You have got to look around before you ( cross ) the street

Tags: word-usage

> You have got to look around before you cross the street.

Can I use *crossing* instead of *cross*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you should remove the second "you".

> You have got to look around before crossing the street.

I prefer

> You must look around before crossing the street.

Comment: You have got to look around before you  crossing the stree. Is this right too?

Comment: No, this answer says the second *you* is incorrect.

Comment: If I want to say,' You have got to look around before he cross the street.', can I say,' You have got to look around before he crossing the street.'?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Weather Vane, though I always learned it as:

> You should look both ways before you cross the street.
>
> You should look both ways before crossing the street.

Comment: If I want to say,' You have got to look around before he cross the street.', can I say,' You have got to look around before he crossing the street.'?

Comment: Firstly, it sounds a bit odd as "you" contradicts with "he", but if you actually mean that the person you are addressing needs to look around before another person crosses the street, you would say: "You have to look around before he crosses the street." (What is the context here?)

Comment: I just imagine "You have to look around before he crosses the street.". There is no context here.

Comment: The way I'd interpret that is that Person A ("you") has to look around before Person B ("he") crosses the street.

Comment: Okay. I know now.